# How to get the editior elements of regex101?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

If we consider this https://regex101.com/r/t1nqwU/1, how can I get this elements :

- REGULAR EXPRESSION
- REGEX OPTIONS
- TEST STRING

When I inspect the page, I understand that I need to query `div class="cm-line"` but my code gives emtpy list.

[image]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://regex101.com/r/t1nqwU/1'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

request = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text)

print(soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'cm-line'}))
[]
```

Can you guys explain why please ? My expected output is this :

```
wanted = {
'regexp': '(\s)(?:line)',
'options': 'gmi',
'string': 'First line\nSecond LINE\nThird line'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content of website is rendered dynamically by `javascript` so you will not find what you are looking for this way, because `requests` do not render information like a browser will do, but you could extract the information from the `script` that holds the initial state of the website.

Locate with `requests` and `regex`:

```
json.loads(
    urllib.parse.unquote(
        re.search(r"window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = '(.*)';", requests.get(url, headers=headers).text).group(1)
    )
)['regexEditor']
```

Locate with `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
json.loads(
    urllib.parse.unquote(
        BeautifulSoup(
            requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
        ).select_one('script:-soup-contains("window.__INITIAL_STATE__")').text.split("'")[1]
    )
)['regexEditor']
```

###### Example

```
import requests, re, json, urllib.parse

url = 'https://regex101.com/r/t1nqwU/1'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

json.loads(
    urllib.parse.unquote(
        re.search(r"window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = '(.*)';", requests.get(url, headers=headers).text).group(1)
    )
)['regexEditor']
```

###### Output

```
{'flavor': 'python',
 'delimiter': '"',
 'flags': 'gmi',
 'regex': '(\\s)(?:line)',
 'testString': 'First line\nSecond LINE\nThird line',
 'matchResult': [],
 'error': None,
 'substString': '',
 'listSubstString': '',
 'hasUnsavedData': False,
 'regexVersions': [],
 'showMatchArea': True,
 'showSubstitutionArea': False,
 'showUnitTestArea': False,
 'showListSubstitutionArea': False}
```

Comment: That's more accurate than what I asked. Thank you so muh HedgeHog.